# Android persisted uri permissions don't persist over device reboot

Tags: android, xamarin, storage-access-framework

Despite calling

```
ContentResolver.TakePersistableUriPermission(uri, ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission | ActivityFlags.GrantWriteUriPermission)
```

on a document tree URI, the URI does not persist over device reboots, although the `ContentResolver.PersistedUriPermissions` property contains the requested URI before the device reboot.  The document tree is obtained like this (per [Storage Access Framework persist permissions not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32563428/storage-access-framework-persist-permissions-not-working)):

```
var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionOpenDocumentTree);
intent.AddFlags(
    ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission |
    ActivityFlags.GrantWriteUriPermission |
    ActivityFlags.GrantPersistableUriPermission | 
    ActivityFlags.GrantPrefixUriPermission);
StartActivityForResult(intent, INTENT_SELECT_TREE);
```

Is there anything I'm missing?  This is on AOSP Lollipop, both in emulator and on hardware.

Comment: You threw away the flags you got. In the link you provided you see `int takeFlags = data.getFlags() & ( 
                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);`. You are not using that.

Comment: Further it does not make sense trying to add flags on an intent used by startactivityforresult. Only the provider can grant the permissions. Not you the consumer.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is working for me:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    var androidUri = data.Data;
    var takeFlags = data.Flags & (ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission | ActivityFlags.GrantWriteUriPermission);
    ContentResolver.TakePersistableUriPermission(androidUri, takeFlags);
}
```